# Nginx fail to redirect

Tags: nginx, https, redirect

I recently pass all my site to https
here is a sample of cv site conf

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name cv.host.com;
   root /www/cv/app;
   index index.html index.htm index.php;
   access_log /www/log/cv/nginx-access.log;
   error_log /www/log/cv/nginx-error.log;
   location /
   {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
   location ~ \.php$
   {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
   }
   listen 443 ssl;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/cv.host.com/fullchain.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/cv.host.com/privkey.pem;
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
   if ($scheme != "https") {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   } # managed by Certbot
}
```

But when i try to open `http://cv.host.com` my browser got redirected to `https://host.com` au lieu de `https://cv.host.com`

Ngninx seem to cal my default conf which is

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    server_name _;    
    root /www/default/app;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;    
    access_log /www/log/default/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /www/log/default/nginx-error.log;    
    location /
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }    
    location ~ \.php$
    {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }    
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/host.com/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;    
    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

So when i ask http://cv.host.com i don't get the good site in https... is my config wrong? Any other way to redirect all to https?

Answer (score -1):

You can't put two vhosts on the same IP for ssl unless its using the same SSL cert.

This is due to how ssl works.. nginx doesn't know anything about the host header until it decrypts the stream. So when it connects at first it is hitting your default entry.

Comment: how i'm supposed to do then? becausereturn 301 https://cv.host.com$request_uri didn't work either

Comment: are you behind and load balancer?

Comment: nop it's a little dedicated server every sub.host.com is a cname to host.com  in my DNS     and all I have to get the good site is nginx and my vhost

Comment: I woud have one server block just for port 80 that redirects everything to 443 and then break out your https server blocks

Comment: to be fair i'm a noob and i had a server on 80 and use certbot to manage my config. it's certbot that generate config like this. with the redirect. so you think my server on 80 must only return to 443 ? and all the content must be in a server for 443? 

Can i have one config file? or must i seperate two server in two file?

Comment: `You can't put two vhosts on the same IP for ssl unless its using the same SSL cert` That is not the case.... This is exactly what SNI solves

Comment: yes which i said.. if its the same cert

Comment: Sorry, not the case. Using SNI nginx will select the correct vhost and certificate within that configuration. I run 5 FQDN all with completely different certificates on a single IP